# Selecting most recent record for each user in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i found this query which i believe is going to solve my problem :

```
SELECT MemberID, ContractID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM member_contracts 
WHERE ContractId IN (
SELECT MAX(ContractId)
FROM member_contracts 
GROUP BY MemberId
)
```

this query hass been given by  @Mark Byers as an answer to another question.

how can i use this query in CodeIgniter especially the "Where_in" clause.

thanks

Comment: `$query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE'); $result = $query->result_array();`

Comment: Mark's solution won't scale very well. Better to stick with the uncorrelated pattern provided in the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use active record library to compile your subquery by using [*`get_compiled_select()`*](http://codeigniter.gen.tr/user_guide/database/active_record.html#this-db-get-compiled-select)

```
$this->db->select('MAX(ContractId)')
         ->from('member_contracts')
         ->group_by('MemberId');
$subquery = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('MemberID, ContractID, StartDate, EndDate')
         ->from('member_contracts ')
         ->where("ContractId  IN($subquery)", NULL, FALSE)
         ->get()
         ->result();
```

Also you can rewrite your query with join instead of sub query to get latest record per group and also a compound index on `MemberId,ContractId` will be useful

```
SELECT m.MemberID, m.ContractID, m.StartDate, m.EndDate
FROM member_contracts m 
JOIN (
SELECT MemberId,MAX(ContractId) ContractId
FROM member_contracts 
GROUP BY MemberId
) mm
USING(MemberId,ContractId)
```

Comment: second suggestion works very well and i like it coz it sticks to sql pattern..thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

In CI, you can use `$this->db->query("yourquery");` to execute a query. Try with

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT MemberID, ContractID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM member_contracts 
WHERE ContractId IN (
SELECT MAX(ContractId)
FROM member_contracts 
GROUP BY MemberId
)");
```